# Did I read 金田 correctly?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, readings

On a kanji reading exercise I read 金田 as kin-den because the on-yomi of 田 is デン. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a name though, and names tend to be kun-yomi.

Comment: Not sure if it's answer worthy but more likely is かねだ...

Comment: That exercise doesn't have a right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The readings of 金田 as a place name and a family name vary.

The reading of 金田 as a family name is usually かねだ, but there are some other readings like かなだ, かなた, きんた, きんだ, かねた, かねこ. But I can't find きんでん.

The readings of 金田 as a place name are かねだ, こんだ, かねた, きんで, かなだ.

Sources:

- [名字由来 - 金田](https://myoji-yurai.net/searchResult.htm?myojiKanji=%E9%87%91%E7%94%B0)
- [Wikipedia - 金田](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%87%91%E7%94%B0)